# How to authenticate and logging in user in laravel using guard?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authentication, laravel-guard

I'm trying to make authentication using guard in Laravel 5.8. Authentication is passed but somehow it's not logging in the user.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
  $email = $request->email;
  $password = $request->password;

  $credentials = $request->only('email','password');

  if (Auth::guard('owner')->attempt($credentials,$request->remember)){

     //echo "Authentication is passed";

     return redirect()->intended('/owner/dashboard');
  }

  return redirect('/owner')->with('error','Login failed.');
}
```

When redirected to route `/owner/dashboard` which is filtered with `$this->middleware('owner')`, the user will be redirected to login form and get notification that login failed. Is `Auth::guard('owner')->attempt($credentials)` only authenticating without logging in user?

Answer (score 0):

in config/auth.php add this 
add new guard and the provider for this guard

````
   'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'owner' => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'owner',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
    ```
    ```
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'owner' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Owner::class,
        ],

    ],

    ```
    ```
      'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'owner' => [
            'provider' => 'owner',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
    ```
    Follow this article
    https://medium.com/@sagarmaheshwary31/laravel-multiple-guards-authentication-setup-and-login-2761564da986
````

Comment: I did that but still, the problem is there

Comment: Did you create  model and table  owners ?

Comment: See this will help you https://medium.com/@sagarmaheshwary31/laravel-multiple-guards-authentication-setup-and-login-2761564da986
it's already as what i answer you

Comment: Read and follow the article i shared in my last comment!